# npm WARN deprecated

Tags: node.js, npm

I wrote this in Git Bash, and got an answer:

```
$ npm install node-sass

npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
```

Does this mean node-sass have old dependencies or packages in my system have old dependencies or could it mean both?

I have tried up to

```
npm list --depth=10
```

but it didn't show me these packages.

I have also tried to upgrade npm, and reinstalled it, cleared the cache

```
npm -g install npm
npm install reinstall -g
npm cache clean -f
```

Comment: Either the `node-sass` module or one of its dependencies needs to be updated or possibly you may need to update your version of node in case a module or one of its dependencies are requiring a newer version of node.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting 'npm WARN deprecated' warnings while running npm install commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35569631/getting-npm-warn-deprecated-warnings-while-running-npm-install-commands)